# LYNX like command in DOS?

Tags: dos

Is there any "lynx" like command DOS? 
I want to get list of all files in a website.

Answer (score 4):

I searched Google for "lynx dos" and found this: http://www.fdisk.com/doslynx/lynxport.htm

Answer (score 3):

there is lynx for dos: http://www.rahul.net/dkaufman/lynx2.8.5rel.1-DOSc.zip (from http://www.rahul.net/dkaufman/)
there is also wget and curl builds for dos (links on the site above) which you can try out

Answer (score 1):

No, there is not.

`telnet` would be the closest, but it's very different :)

Comment: Actually i want to know all files in a website

Comment: Right, you're looking for a `spider` or `crawler`. Search for either of those and you will find what you want :)